# Is there a way to execute code just before page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, url

I've been trying to do this with the **onbeforeunload** function but it just

doesn't do what I want.

So, I have a web page that appends text to its url to do some stuff:

```
https://localhost:3000/someTextAppended
```

But when I refresh, either by clicking the browser "refresh button" or pressing

"F5", I don't want to refresh the new url (with the appended text), I just want to

refresh the domain part in this case:

```
https://localhost:3000
```

I tried with this code and some variants:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  window.history.pushState("data","Title","");
});
```

But it keeps refreshing the appended url and then I get .

```
Cannot GET /someTextAppended
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem - what are you trying to achieve

Comment: don't use pushState to set invalid URLs; everything to do with proper dynamic history should be reflected on the server's url interface as well. The is an onunload event that fires at the right time, but again, you should avoid such an anti-pattern as temporary client-only URLs; there's no point to them whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few things you can do in `onbeforeunload`.  Sending the user somewhere else isn't one of them.

> So, I have a web page that appends text to its url to do some stuff

The URL should be indicative of the place the user is in your site or applicatoin.  It shouldn't "do some stuff".

What you should probably be doing is keeping state in LocalStorage, and updating the URL *on page load* if the state represented in the URL isn't valid.

I'd give you specific advice, but you didn't ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for you but you could use the `location.hash` (`https://localhost:3000/#someTextAppended`).

Alternatively, set up your web server to serve `/` on a `GET /someTextAppended` request.